# How to display MySQL table data onto JTextPane as per JTextField ID

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

[image: NetBeans GUI]

I have a MySQL table named **assp1** with a field named, *StudentID*, a field named *Maths* and another *maths_percentage*. I also have designed a NetBeans GUI which is shown above, with a JTextField named as *jtxtStudentID* and a JTextPane named *jtxtTranscript*. I also have a JButton on the NetBeans GUI. What I want to do is, when I enter a particular studentID in the JTextField *jtxtStudentID* and click on the JButton, I want the *Maths* and *maths_percentage* data on **assp1** displayed on the JTextPane *jtxtTranscript*, which is under the Result section of the GUI. The data to be displayed must depend on the StudentID entered into the JTextField. Please help me achieve that. Thank you. Below is my code. When I run it, it gives **java.lang.NullPointerException**.

```
private void jbtnTranscriptsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
jtxtTranscript.setText(null);
 StyledDocument doc=(StyledDocument) jtxtTranscript.getDocument();
 Style style= doc.addStyle("StyleName", null);
try {
if(jtxtStudent!=null){
Connection conn=MySqlConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=null;
 String qry=null; 
qry=" SELECT maths_percentage FROM assp1\n"
+ " where StudentID=?";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ps.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(jtxtStudent.getText()));
rs=stmt.executeQuery(qry);
 while(rs.next()){
int mathPerc=rs.getInt("maths_percentage"); 
 doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), "\n\t\t STUDENT ACADEMIC REPORT : Assessment Period 1\t\n"
+ "\t\t\t\t"+mathPerc+"\n"
 , style);
 }
}else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error retrieving % from database");
 }
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(Term2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(Assp1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
```

Comment: Ok what is your problem? Do you know how to use a JButton and do processing when the button is clicked? Do you know how to use SQL and do an SQL query? Do you know how to update text in a text pane. State the "specific" problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you for the respond. I will update my original question with my existing codes to show you what I need done.

Comment: *When I run it, it gives java.lang.NullPointerException.* - well we can't compile and execute that code, so we have no idea which statement is causing the problem.. And even if we could we don't have access to your database. So you need to do basic debugging. The Exception will tell you the statement causing the problem. So determine which variable is null and then fix the problem.